# Correct use of polymorphism in containers?

Tags: c++, enums, polymorphism, containers

In this code I've started working on, I came across a common pattern that somehow doesn't sit right with me. Usually, it involves an enum, a map, a switch and some sort of class hierarchy. I've tried to abstract a MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Shape {
public:
    virtual double SumOfInternalAngles() { throw std::exception(); }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
public:
    double SumOfInternalAngles() { return 180.0; }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    double SumOfInternalAngles() { return 360.0; }
};

enum TeamShapes {AlicesTriangle, BobsRectangle, CarolsTriangle};

int main()
{
    Triangle alicesTriangle;
    Rectangle bobsRectangle;
    Triangle carolsTriangle;

    std::map<TeamShapes, Shape*> shapeMap;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::AlicesTriangle] = &alicesTriangle;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::BobsRectangle] = &bobsRectangle;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::CarolsTriangle] = &carolsTriangle;

    for(auto it : shapeMap)
    {
        switch (it.first)
        {
        case TeamShapes::AlicesTriangle:
            std::cout << it.second->SumOfInternalAngles() << std::endl;
            break;

        case TeamShapes::BobsRectangle:
            std::cout << static_cast<Rectangle*>(it.second)->SumOfInternalAngles() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be repetitive information, and both versions of accessing the member function have drawbacks: In the first case, you need to have a virtual member function in the base class, which means that all the derived classes get "cluttered" with functions that don't really make sense for them, e.g. a `Circle` would end up with a function `getCorners()`. In the second case I would prefer not needing the cast, although I know that it is necessary. Maybe someone can point me in a direction where I can come up with a better design for this case.

I'm quite new to C++, so I'd like to hear what the "best practices" and "conventions" regarding such constructs are. Maybe the code is fine, and I simply need to adjust?

Comment: `for(auto it` makes a copy of the key-value pair in the map. Doesn't matter much here, but generally you will want `for(auto &it`.

Comment: Why do you think the cast is necessary in your example?  It isn't.

Comment: I know that is not necessary (I've used the version without 3 lines above the one with it), but I would prefer not to have `SumOfInternalAngles` in the base class, and then it would be necessary.

Comment: Don't put related types in the same container, but then treat them differently (by trying to access derived class methods). If you need to treat your objects differently consider keeping them in [separate containers](https://bannalia.blogspot.de/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is probably exactly what is bothering me. The map of `Shape` to use polymorphism, and then the enum and switch to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your base class pure virtual (i.e make the class abstract), then you don't have to implement `SumOfInternalAngles()` in it and thus no need to throw an exception. Shape then becomes an abstract interface to be implemented by a derived class and this derived class MUST implement `SumOfInternalAngles()`.

Then in your switch statement, you don't need to cast unless you wanted to call a method specific to the derived class such as `getCorners()` which may or may not be present in all derived versions of `Shape`.

To do this simply change you shape definition to

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual double SumOfInternalAngles() = 0;
};
```

And use the first version of your switch case.

i.e

```
 case TeamShapes::AlicesTriangle:
         std::cout << it.second->SumOfInternalAngles() << std::endl;
         break;

 case TeamShapes::BobsRectangle:
         std::cout << it.second->SumOfInternalAngles() << std::endl;
         break;
```

EDIT: some sample code to try and help illustrate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class base
{
public:

    virtual std::string AMethodThatMustBeImplemented() = 0;
    virtual std::string ABaseMethod() { return std::string("base::ABaseMethod"); }
};

class A : public base
{
public:
    virtual std::string AMethodThatMustBeImplemented() { return std::string("A::AMethodThatMustBeImplmented"); }
    // No need to implment ABaseMethod here unless we wanted to!
};

class B : public base
{
public:
    virtual std::string AMethodThatMustBeImplemented() { return std::string("B::AMethodThatMustBeImplmented"); }
    virtual std::string ABaseMethod() { return std::string("B::ABaseMethod"); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //base obj;     // can't do this since base has 'pure virtual' called AMethodThatMustBeImplemented.

    A objA;
    B objB;

    std::cout << objA.AMethodThatMustBeImplemented() << '\n';
    std::cout << objA.ABaseMethod() << '\n';
    std::cout << objB.AMethodThatMustBeImplemented() << '\n';
    std::cout << objB.ABaseMethod() << '\n';

    base& b = static_cast<base&>(objB);
    std::cout << b.ABaseMethod() << "   <- notice still calling B::ABaseMethod\n";
    std::cout << b.base::ABaseMethod() << "    <- ah-ha now calling base::ABaseMethod\n";

}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But any "specific" method like `getCorners` would still need either the cast or the exception, because I don't want to force `Circle` to implement it, right?

Comment: You have two choices... either the caller knows the specifics about a type (in this case `Circle`) and thus casts to that type and call `getCorners()` which is only defined in class `Circle`, or `getCorners()` is part of the `Shape` interface and you implement `getCorners() { throw Exception("An unspecified shape has no concept of corners"); }` the same way you did originally for `SumOfInternalAngles()`. What this means is that `getCorners()` only needs to be implemented in the derived classes that you want (the syntax does not need to be duplicated for every class declaration).

Comment: If a caller calls `getCorners()` and the class has it (i.e its of type `Circle`) `Circle::getCorners()` will be called. If the derived class does not have `getCorners()`, then the base method will be called (`Shape::getCorners()`). Put simply, if declared pure virtual ( i.e with '=0' at the end) it MUST be implemented in dervied. If it is simply 'virtual' (and implemented in the base class) you do not have to implement in derived.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is an intermediate interface for your derived class, in this case a "Polygon" interface derived from "Shape", which has methods that make sense for polygons, but not for a circle for example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>

class IShape {
public:
    virtual double getArea() = 0;
};

class IPolygon : public IShape {
public:
    virtual double sumOfInternalAngles() = 0;
};


class Triangle : public IPolygon {
public:
    Triangle(double _base, double _height) : base(_base), height(_height) {}

    double sumOfInternalAngles() { return 180.0; }
    double getArea() { return (base * height)/2; }

private:
    double base;
    double height;
};

class Rectangle : public IPolygon {
public:
    Rectangle(double _width, double _height) : width(_width), height(_height) {}

    double sumOfInternalAngles() { return 360.0; }
    double getArea() { return (width * height); }

public:
    double width;
    double height;
};

class Circle : public IShape {
public:
    Circle(double _radius) : radius(_radius) {}

    double getArea() { return (3.14 * pow(radius,3)); }

public:
    double radius;
};


enum TeamShapes {AlicesTriangle, BobsRectangle, CarolsCircle};

int main()
{
    Triangle alicesTriangle(10,10);
    Rectangle bobsRectangle(10,10);
    Circle carolsCircle(10);

    std::map<TeamShapes, IShape*> shapeMap;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::AlicesTriangle] = &alicesTriangle;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::BobsRectangle] = &bobsRectangle;
    shapeMap[TeamShapes::CarolsCircle] = &carolsCircle;

    for(const auto& it : shapeMap)
    {
        switch (it.first)
        {
        case TeamShapes::AlicesTriangle:
        case TeamShapes::BobsRectangle:
            std::cout << static_cast<IPolygon*>(it.second)->sumOfInternalAngles() << std::endl;
            std::cout << it.second->getArea() << std::endl;
            break;

        case TeamShapes::CarolsCircle:
            std::cout << it.second->getArea() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You still have to cast your pointer, but I find it preferable to a non virtual method which throw an exception.